# place dynamic query inside IF EXISTS conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic

i tried to store the dynamic query inside IF EXISTS conditions in SQL Server

```
create procedure temp_order
(
@tbl varchar (max)
)
as
begin
IF EXISTS ('SELECT * FROM ' + @tbl + ' where cd = 1')
end
```

but it looks like dynamic query wont work inside "IF EXISTS" condition, 
any ways to make the condition if the tables is exist or not?

Comment: This doesn't execute the query. It's just a string.  Change the sql to 'select Top(1) 1 from ' + @tbl + ' where cd = 1'.  Execute it and assign the result to a variable. Then check the value.

Comment: DO NOT directly execute sql when part of the dynamic string is from a parameter. This is the textbook definition of sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use dynamic sql for this but use dynamic sql with sp_executesql and quotename function as shown below, else you code maybe prone to sql-injection attack.

```
create procedure temp_order
(
  @tbl    SYSNAME,   --<-- use appropriate data type
  @Exists INT    OUTPUT
)
as
begin
 Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Sql = N'IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tbl) 
                     + N' where cd = 1)'
           + N'BEGIN
                SET @Exists = 1;
               END
              ELSE 
               BEGIN
                 SET @Exists = 0;
               END'

  Exec sp_executesql @sql 
                    ,N'@Exists INT OUTPUT'
                    ,@Exists OUTPUT

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
DECLARE @I TABLE(I INT)
declare @sql varchar(1000) = 'select top(1) 1 from ' + @tbl + ' with(nolock) where cd = 1'
INSERT INTO @i EXEC (@sql)
IF EXISTS (select 1 from @i) Print 'exists' else print 'doesn''t exist'
```

If this suits your need, then depending on the source of the parameter, see what 'defensive measures' to take to protect against injections and such.

Comment: this is prone to sql injection attack :S

Comment: Only if you don't have control over the source of the parameters sent.  And why I also noted to see first if it helps as a proof of concept.  If for instance the source of the parameter is an internal query, then there is no danger.  You can't just post "sql injection" on every dynamic sql and cancel it.   It's a tool. And a very effective one when used correctly.

Comment: Yes When used correctly, and you certainly haven't since it is prone to SQL injection, your idea of having control over parameter values doesn't make sense, once your code is out there in production I don't know how you can have control on anything other than making your code so good that it can stand its ground , they say "if it can go wrong , it will go wrong"